# xna 16bit texture looks like 8bit

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xna

I have a 16bit texture that is displayed on a model in an xna+silverlight app.

Here is the texture

[image]

But, it is rendered like this:

[image: rendered]

I tried loading png instead of jpg, loading from stream and some other stuff I forgot, but nothing seems to work.

**Update:**
I tried setting PreferredBackBufferFormat to SurfaceFormat.Color, nothing changed.

**Update2:**
Xna is displaying in 16bit by default. 5 bit for R, 6G and 5 B. After converting my texture to 565 it looks exactly like the one rendered.

There probably is no solution that would satisfy me, so I'm will be trying some other approach.

Comment: Can you post your exact original texture?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the second picture is scaled up so it gets blurry.

Comment: It looks like quantisation from storing the image in an 8 bit buffer at some point.  What format is the framebuffer?

Comment: Updated. Doesn't xna have 16bit buffer by default?

Answer (score 2):

On Windows Phone 7, is you want to use 32 bits colors, you have to explicitely activate it in the application manifest.

Open the `WMAppManifest.xml` file, search the `App` node, and add the attribute `BitsPerPixel="32"`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769509(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help.